# Is it possible to get virtual property in Mongoose query result?

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm looking for (and can't find any) elegant solution how to use virtual property *fullName* in Mongoose model Person.

**Person.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PersonSchema = new Schema(
    {
        firstName: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
        lastName: {type: String, required: true, max: 100}
    }
);

PersonSchema
    .virtual('fullName')
    .get(function () {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

Actually I have access to fullName, but don't know how to add it to result object.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');

require('./connectDB');
const Person = require('./Person');

const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await Person.find();
    result.map((person) => {
        console.log('Virtual fullName property: ', person.fullName); 
        // console print:            
        // Jane Smith
    });
    console.log('All returned persons: ', result);
    // console print:
    // [{ _id: 5ad9f4f25eecbd2b1c842be9,
    //    firstName: 'Jane',
    //    lastName: 'Smith',
    //    __v: 0 }]

    res.send({result});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server has started at port 3000');
});
```

So, if you have any ideas how to use virtuals, please post it

**Solution (thanks to Jason)**

Add this code to **Person.js** before model export:

```
PersonSchema
    .set('toObject', { getters: true });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject) for schemas:

> To have all virtuals show up in your `console.log` output, set the `toObject` option to `{ getters: true }`

By default, virtual paths are not included in a conversion from a mongoose document to a POJO. `console.log` causes mongoose to automatically invoke this conversion.

Updating `PersonSchema` with this option will enable the virtual to be included in the logged output:

```js
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 100
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 100
  }
}, {
  getters: true
});
```

A full list of the `toObject` options can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject).

Comment: what's the difference between getters: true and virtuals : true in these options?  any ideas?  They seem to be the same, but different !

Answer (score 5):

for including the virtual in `res.send()` on express set `PersonSchema.set("toJSON", { getters: true });` on schema.

Answer (score 1):

In order to include virtual property to the mongoose query result so that you can get it from api end do the following in your Data Model Schema:

```
PersonSchema
    .set('toObject', { getters: true });
```